# Synchronize module fails with become

Tags: ansible

I am trying to use the synchronize module to copy a file from an Ansible node to a remote one.

I want these files to exist as `UserB` on the remote nodes but I do not have access to `UserB` directly. Instead `UserA` has sudo privileges to switch to `UserB`. So I'm logging in as `UserA`.

My environment file says:

```
ansible_ssh_user=UserA
ansible_ssh_pass=<PassUserA>
ansible_become_method=sudo
ansible_become_user=UserB
ansible_become_pass=<PassUserA>
```

My task is:

```
- name: Copy and unarchive webapps node.
  synchronize: src=/home/ansible/templates/app/Sprint6/webapps dest=/opt/msdp/ca/app checksum=yes
  become: yes
```

But when I run the playbook, I get an error:

```
fatal: [5.232.57.247]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "cmd": "/usr/bin/rsync --delay-updates -F --compress --checksum --archive --rsh 'ssh  -S none -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s' --rsync-path=\"sudo rsync\" --out-format='<<CHANGED>>%i %n%L' \"/home/ansible/templates/app/Sprint6/webapps\" \"UserA@5.232.57.247:/opt/msdp/ca/app\"", "failed": true, "msg": "sudo: sorry, you must have a tty to run sudo\nrsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [sender]\nrsync error: error in rsync protocol data stream (code 12) at io.c(600) [sender=3.0.6]\n", "rc": 12}
```

On the remote node, only `UserB` can write under: `/opt/msdp/ca/app`

Is there a config that I am missing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`synchronize`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/synchronize_module.html) module is executed locally on the control machine (not on the target node) and by default it connects to the nodes with the account (SSH credentials) used there (currently logged-in one, or defined in `~/.ssh/config`).

First, you need to override the default behaviour by adding the `use_ssh_args` parameter for the `ansible_ssh_*` values to be considered when connecting:

> `use_ssh_args` Use the ssh_args specified in `ansible.cfg`

---

Second, because the task is run locally, `become` directive is also effective only on the control machine. `ansible_become_*` variables do not apply in this situation.

Instead, you can tell the module to run `sudo rsync` to elevate the permissions on the target node through the `rsync_path` parameter:

```
- name: Copy and unarchive webapps node.
  synchronize:
    src: /home/ansible/templates/app/Sprint6/webapps
    dest: /opt/msdp/ca/app checksum=yes
    use_ssh_args: yes
    rsync_path: "sudo -u UserB rsync"
```

---

Finally, the above assumes sudoers settings allowing passwordless sudo. If you really need to provide a password in plain text, you'd need another workaround in the like of:

```
rsync_path: "echo {{ UserA_password }} | sudo -S -u UserB rsync"
```

Comment: Thanks for your detailed reply. I completely understood point 2 and 3 but I have problems understanding 1. What you mean to say is that if I enable ssh_args= under  /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg , it will start using whatever I have defined in the lab file ? But I am already able to use those properties while connecting to my target node.

Comment: No, those properties are not used for `synchronize` module and that's why it has additional parameter `use_ssh_args`. I don't know how to express it differently. `synchronize` module is run locally and is different from other modules. Did you check the doc page I linked? It basically states the same.

Comment: Thanks techraf ! I get it now. And apologies for "lab" file. I meant environment file.

Answer (score 0):

Check for `Defaults requiretty` in the `/etc/sudoers` of the target system and replace the line with `Defaults !requiretty`

Or disable `requiretty` for the Ansible user:

```
Defaults!/path/to/my/bin !requiretty
Defaults:myansibleuser !requiretty
```

Check this [site](https://www.shell-tips.com/2014/09/08/sudo-sorry-you-must-have-a-tty-to-run-sudo/) for more options.

Comment: Thanks Henrik ! One question. On the target system, I do not have an Anisible user. i login as UserA and then switch over to UserB. In this case I should disable requiretty for UserA, right ?

Comment: I just did `Defaults    !requiretty` and now Im getting : `sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified`. Do I need to change any sudo privelages on the Anible node ?